# How to implement functional unit testing sinon with mocks in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, sinon

How to implement sinon.mock on follwing function.

> function getDashboard(req,res){
>       res.send("success");
>       }

```
describe("GetDashboard test"){
    it("Response Should be test", function(){
        const getDashboard = sinon.stub().returns('success');
        let req = {}     
        let res = {
        send: function(){};
        const mock = sinon.mock(res);     
        mock.expect(getDashboard.calledOnce).to.be.true;      
        mock.verify();
      }    
    })
}
```

Also how to stubbing data in function.Is it correct way of mocking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');

function getDashboard(req, res) { res.send('success'); }

describe("getDashboard", function () {
  it("should respond with 'success'", function () {
    const req = {};
    const res = { send: sinon.stub() };
    getDashboard(req, res);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(res.send, 'success');  // Success!
  })
});
```

---

**Details**

`getDashboard` calls the `send` function of the `res` object that it is given, so you just need to create a mock object with a `sinon` stub for the `send` property and verify that it was called as expected.